# App Keeps Crashing Found Nil Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display a webview in my app.  The url for the webview is in object format because i got it from json. So in my code i converted the object to NSString and tried to load the view but my app crashes saying this: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.  Is there a better way to convert object to string? How can i get the webview to display the url content?

Where Detail Item is made:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object: AnyObject = objectsPath[indexPath.row]
        (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).detailItem = object
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
  var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() -> NSURLRequest {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem!
        let stringURL: String = String(detail as NSString)
        let url = NSURL(string: stringURL)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!) <---ERROR occurs here
        return request



           // let string:St= detailItem!
          //  previewWebView.
           // println(string)
            //let url = NSURL(string: string)
            //let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            //self.previewWebView.loadRequest(request)

        }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.previewWebView.loadRequest(configureView())

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Where did the error occur?

Comment: Where do you set `detailItem`? Your `viewDidLoad` is calling `configureView`, which is unwrapping `detailItem` without checking to see if it's `nil` or not (and there's nothing here that ever sets `detailItem`, so I'd expect it to be `nil` and give you precisely this error). Also, don't use `AnyObject` unless you have to. If `detailItem` a `String`, then just define it as such and get rid of all of the casting and converting gyrations in `configureView`.

Comment: I have updated the question. Also this is detailpage of tableview if that matters

Comment: Is objectsPath an array of Strings?

Comment: Yes objectsPath is a mutableArray of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `configureView()` within your `viewDidLoad()` with no regard for the value of `self. detailItem`. You should be checking for a value before calling this function in `viewDidLoad()` or you should modify `configureView()` to not claim there is definitely a value of `self.detailItem`.

Comment: hahah yea i got it now removed self, dumb mistake haha. Thanks for your help!